# How do I display a button on a UIAlertView after displaying it

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am newbie developing with objective C.

I am working on a piece of code that installs a plugin to my application. It downloads a .zip package, uncompress it and copy some data to my sqlite database.

I have a `UIAlertView` that shows a `UIProgressView` while the app is downloading and uncompressing, when it finish I add to the `UIAlertView` a button with the `addButtonWithTitle` method.

I dont know why my button appears on the top-left corner of my UIAlertView.

This is a piece of my code:

```
ventana = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Instalando %@", codigo] 
                                             message:@"Por favor, no apague el dispositivo ni cierre la aplicación." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles: nil];

actividad = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
actividad.frame = CGRectMake(20, 110, 20, 20);

progreso = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 115, 215, 9)];
[ventana addSubview:actividad];
[actividad startAnimating];
[ventana addSubview:progreso];
[ventana show];

-- some stuff (downloading, uncompressing, updating my UIProgressView...) --
[progreso removeFromSuperview];
[actividad removeFromSuperview];
[ventana addButtonWithTitle:@"Aceptar"];
ventana.message = @"Instalación finalizada";
```

I have a image but I can't post it here because I am a new user.

Anyone knows why my button appears at the top-left corner of my UIAlertView (ventana)
Thanks!

Comment: If you can put the image on the web somewhere, you can post a link to the image that people can see.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are using the `UIAlertView` is sort of... bad.  You should *never*show a UIAlertView with 0 buttons, and using it as a 'don't turn off the device' message is a bad idea.  The "accepted" use for the alert view is to tell the user something important has just happened.  If you insist, however, you should have a cancel button in there by default so they can stop the operation if they want to, then when it's finished, add the button.  The `UIAlertView` may be confused when trying to add a button to a list of buttons that doesn't exist (because you initialized it with 0 buttons).

However, the better way to go about it would be to show a progress indicator while downloading (which you have) on a general `UIView` with a `UILabel` containing the message.  Then, when it's completed, change the label to show your "Instalación finalizada" message, and display a button below it.  I know, it seems like it's just replicating what you already have, but there's nowhere in your description that I see that calls for the use of a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: OK, I have put an initial cancel button, but my final accept button stil appears at the top-left corner of the UIAlertView.

I'm using the UIAlertView because I want an small window with the UIAlert style (transparet blue, rounded corners, etc.) Can I do it with an UIView? or it's wrong too?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you actually use a UIAlertView or replicate the way it looks.  Conceptually, it's the same to the end user, and that's what the Apple HIG is talking about when it says when and when not to use a UIAlertView.